# Terraform eks datasource vpc subnets security group

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform script which creates an eks cluster 
I have another terraform script which creates a rds ,I want this rds to be created
in the same VPC as the eks cluster .

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

output "subnets" {
  value = "${data.aws_eks_cluster.example.vpc_config.vpc_id}"
}
```

here is my rds.tf

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "rds" {
 allocated_storage    = "${var.rds_allocated_storage}"
 storage_type         = "${var.rds_storage_type}"
 engine               = "${var.rds_engine}"
 engine_version       = "${var.rds_engine_version}"
 instance_class       = "${var.rds_instance_class}"
 name                 = "${var.project_name}_${var.env}_data_rds${var.rds_engine}"
 username             = "dbadmin"
 password             = "${var.rds_db_password}"
 multi_az             = false
 skip_final_snapshot  = true
 db_subnet_group_name = "${aws_db_subnet_group.rds_subnet.name}"
 vpc_security_group_ids = "${var.rds_vpc_security_group_ids}"
 identifier  = "${var.project_name}-${var.env}-data-rds${var.rds_engine}"
```

I want to get db_subnet_group_name and  vpc_security_group_ids from my eks 
and not from variables.tf

Comment: this works for 0.11 of terraform for 0.12 it has to be changed to [0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need something like

```
vpc_security_group_ids = "${data.aws_eks_cluster.example.vpc_config.0.security_group_ids}"
```